# 530 authentication problem in Windows Live Mail on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, authentication, windows-live-mail

I get following message when trying to send an e-mail bu:

> 530 authentication required

How do I resolve this problem?

I'm working on Windows 7 and trying to use Windows Live Mail with my existing e-mail address.

Answer (score 0):

Who is your email server? This is a configuration issue on your Windows Live Mail. I would refer to your mail server to make sure you have POP/IMAP access enabled. Usually you can google "Set up windows live mail with xxxxxx mail" where xxxxxx is your mail provider.

Answer (score 0):

Most SMTP servers these days require authentication for submitting mail. Make sure you enabled *Accounts* → *Properties* → *Servers* → *Outgoing* → *My server requires authentication*, otherwise WLM will not even attempt to login.